Не получается запустить turtlebot3_gazebo на Ubuntu 22

Установил уже все, что только можно, но не получается запустить команду ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
Выдает ошибку: Package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found: "package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/humble']" 
Использую Ubuntu 22 от Jammy, установлена ros2 humble

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Пробовал и сносить систему и инсталлировать через гитхаб, помогло установить симуляцию turtlebot3
Кому интересно, вроде брал команды отсюда - https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/
